# scrollr - parallax scrolling with pseudo-fixed image ratio in full width size

Tags: javascript, php, css, parallax, image-resizing

I have build my first parallax website based on Petr Tichy's very good tutorial. I recommend it (https://ihatetomatoes.net).

Here is my new site.  The idea was to get an attractive intro for this new project using altered-perspective images in full width.
http://www.ticket2ut...Alpha/zHome.php

I have already spent hours and hours and read so many articles and tutorials... but I still struggle a bit especially that I want to control the ratio of the images in a certain way.  They must always be full page but depending on the width of the browser window, I apply a certain correction to the height.  As the whole project is about "changing your perspective"... it's great... IMO.

However, I would like to change the height of the picture when the browser window is square or taller than wide.  I have tried so many different things... but nothing works.  The problem is that the background-attachment must be fixed to work with parallax and I can not change that.  At the moment I just resize the browser window to the ratio of the image (16/9) but this is not ideal at all.  I control the situation when the browser window is wide, but in the case it's not I would like to force the image to its exact ratio to start with.

How can I achieve that?

There is also a section at the bottom of the page (#20 - visual meditation) which I can not control properly... the text box should fade in and out later.  I used the code : data-100-top="opacity: 1"  data-center="opacity: 1" data-center-top="opacity: 0" data--100-bottom="opacity: 0;" data-anchor-target="#slide-20".  What should be changed to get the text in the box appear later and stay longer on?

Greetings from Cape Town, Paul

Comment: I would suggest being more to the point - would probably help you get answers - see here [mcve]

Comment: If you're able to cut down the question to the barest you can, present your code, what you're looking for it to do, and then what it is doing. It seems like the data's all there but it's very verbose. The more discrete the question is, the better the answers.